# Rails 3.2 nested routes and AJAX

Tags: ajax, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2 and have created a simple test blog application.  There is a Post model and a Comment model where a post `has_many :comments` and a comment `belongs_to :post`.

**in routes.rb:**

```
resources "posts" do
  resources "comments"
end
```

I display the comments at the bottom of the parent post's page and submit new comments via AJAX.  Therefore, I think it is unnecessary for the user to be able to visit /posts/1/comments/XXX.  However, if I remove `resources "comments"` from my routes then the commenting functionality doesn't work anymore.  How can I prevent the user from visiting /posts/1/comments/XXX in the browser but keep the commenting AJAX functionality working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do as a solution is condition the route with the request being a xhr request. You can do it the following way:

```
# routes.rb
class OnlyAjaxRequest
  def matches?(request) 
    request.xhr?
  end
end

resources "posts" do
  resources "comments", :constraints => OnlyAjaxRequest.new
end
```

You can find more info about routing constraints in [this blog post](http://railsadventures.wordpress.com/2012/10/07/routing-only-ajax-requests-in-ror/).